# Javascript projects to learn from

Tags: javascript, open-source, project

I like javascript, but I have problem with learning it :)
I mean, i use it at work but I would like to know more, and I think the best way to do it is to read and understand someone else's code.

I use ASP.Net MVC and there are some great opensource projects you can use to learn new technology, like NerdDinner, Oxite or SharpArchitecture or even MS starterkits.
I was trying to read frameworks like jQuery, but it's really complicated, and I don't think that it was created to learn new things from it.

Do you know any good JS projects that can help with learning javascript ?

I'll try to paste all good sources here :

- [Github - javascript](http://github.com/languages/JavaScript)
- [JS Made Easy](http://www.jsmadeeasy.com/)

Nice JS tutorial: [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html)

Comment: What particular aspects of js do you want to know more about? Is there something you see a lot but don't understand, or something you want to do but don't know how?

Comment: I think I know javascript quite well, but I don't think that reading books/tutorials is the best way to learn more.

Comment: *Eh?* You said you already tried the jQuery source but it was *too complicated*, so how would looking at complex scripts improve your knowledge if you aren't learning anything because they're too much for you? Books and tutorials feature code snippets, and usually ones simpler than complex source like jQuery along with step by step explanations. They can range from very simple to complex, so I don't see how you can't learn from books/tutorials. I myself am experienced with JS but I can easily learn from books/tutorials. I think only a genius or an adept coder can only learn DIRECTLY from code.

Comment: I can learn from books/tutorials. I just prefer learning from someone else's code, look how to accomplish tasks.
I don't agree that you can't learn from code if you know the language. I know I said that jQuery was hard for me, maby I'm just to lazy and with a little bit of effort I could understand all, but I would like to find something easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at some of the JavaScript projects hosted on Github: **https://github.com/search?q=javascript&ref=cmdform**

Comment: Can you update the url. it is broken.

Answer (score 7):

There's a great interactive tutorial for learning JS, [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html) which I would really recommend. Since you already mentioned you tried learning jQuery by the source and it was hard, why not just go this route?

Comment: It is totally different from what I was asking for, 
but it's a relly great link ! THX.

Answer (score 6):

In essence all javascript is open source. You just go to the webpage and view source.

If you open the JS file directly you will see its source.

There are of course exceptions, with people trying to obfuscate javascript, but they are the minority.

Checkout [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) to learn more.

Another good source is the talks of Douglas Crockford on javascript. Google has a bunch of them, [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=ocF&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&tbs=vid%3A1&q=javascript+douglas+crockford&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Comment: Ok, i know that js is opensource :) but try to read it when it's compressed :)

Comment: @Jarek - there are tools out there to "pretty print" javascript and to reverse obfuscation.

Comment: ok, but again, I'm not looking for a tutorial, or a screencast. I've already seen D. Crockford series, I even have his book :) (I was translated to Polish ;p). As i wrote before, jQuery is really hard to learn from and jquery plugins sometimes are the worst javascript code I've ever seen :)

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to take a look at [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) project.

It's an open source javascript library for creating web mapping "Google Maps"-like applications.

It's a good example of how to write solid, testable and maintainable object oriented javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check out the JQuery tutorial pages? They contain a lot of practical examples
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 3):

http://www.jsmadeeasy.com/
scripts exaples - learn by example

Comment: Learning from examples that start like this — `<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> <!-- n = (document.layers) ? 1:0; ie = (document.all) ? 1:0` — does more harm than good and is probably one of the worst places to start with.

Answer (score 0):

http://learn.appendto.com/
A FREE video course on Javascript/jQuery
The best thing I've found so far to grasp JS/jQuery quickly.

Answer (score 0):

backbone.js @ http://backbonejs.org/

Also,
The Narcissus meta-circular JavaScript interpreter - https://github.com/mozilla/narcissus